# <a href="path to dir"> won't to download as a PHP echo

Tags: php, download, echo

When I use echo to show all stuff in folder the echo function doesn´t work for download these files.

Does anybody know why it doesn´t work ? When I see source in explorer (F12) everything looks good and should work - but it doesn´t.

Here is the code:

```
<?php  
            $allFiles = scandir('files/');
            $files = array_diff($allFiles, array('.', '..'));

            foreach($files as $file)
                {   
                echo "<a href src='files/".$file."' download>
                        <div class='download-folder'>
                            <div class='folder-image'></div>
                            <p>".$file."</p>
                        </div>
                      </a>";
                }

         ?>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remove the `src` from the `href`. `src` is for images and scripts.

Comment: OMG .. thank you, it was such a stupid mistake. Thx

Comment: You're welcome Rudi.

Comment: Answers were given after my comment. I'll post my own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `src` from the `href`. `src` is used for images and scripts.

```
echo "<a href='files/".$file."' download>
        <div class='download-folder'>
            <div class='folder-image'></div>
            <p>".$file."</p>
        </div>
      </a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a href src="...` is the problem. `<a>` tags do NOT have a `src`.

```
 <a href="$pathtofile">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your link to `'<a href="$pathtofile" download>'` and it should works.

Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) to show the usage of `download` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Change this -

```
echo "<a href src='files/".$file."' download>
```

to this -

```
echo "<a href='files/".$file."' download>
```

Anchor tags do not have sources.